# copy vim text, colors included

Tags: vim

I have a vim open on code, and the code is highlighted. I would like to write this code to a file, including the color codes used to highlight the text. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vim's `TOHtml` achieves this. It saves the active buffer with the syntax coloring as HTML. It might be included in your Vim installation, so try ahead issuing `:TOhtml`.

Comment: This is the most badass thing I've ever seen. +1 million

Comment: Really awesome.. +1 billion

Comment: alias vimtohtml="vim -c 'set nonu' -c TOhtml -c wqa" - To directly convert without opening the file in vim:
vimtohtml <filename>